# autocomplete: clean up input field after select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `autocomplete` and when I select item from dropdown it fills input form with the selected value. I need to remove this value after select. Here is the snippet

```
$( "[name='resource-keyword']" ).autocomplete({
    source: $('[name*="tagger_names"]').map(function() {return $(this).val();}).get(),
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        form.prepend('<input type="hidden" name="tags[]" value="'+ui.item.value+'">');
        $('ul.tags').append('<li><a href="" title="Evidence">'+ui.item.value+'</a></li>');
        $( "[name='resource-keyword']" ).val("");
        form.submit();
    },
    change: function(){
        $( "[name='resource-keyword']" ).val("");
    }
```

But that not work.
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#target" ).blur(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
});
```

Have you tried the blur event?